# Why is this error Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined happening in firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm trying to get a specific doc from my firestore database. So I matched the `slug` field in the doc. But it throws me an error...

> Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

My syntax looks like this

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { slug } = context.params;

  const res = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("books")
    .where("slug", "==", slug)
    .get();

  const book = res.docs.map((book) => book.data());

  if (book.length) {
    return {
      props: {
        book: book[0],
      },
    };
  } else {
    return {
      props: {},
    };
  }
}
```

and my firestore document looks like

[image]

BTW I'm using Next.Js's SSG.

Comment: quotes in second slug argument? `.where("slug", "==", "slug")` ?

Comment: Look what I did is pul out the slug value from URL param. `const { slug } = context.params;`. I can't put a double quote in it.

Comment: I believe it's complaining that the `slug` variable is undefined. Is your `getStaticPaths` returning all the correct, possible paths? Maybe it's worth having an early return if `slug` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It is because in the getStaticPaths `slug` is not returned.
You've to return the same name(here slug) in params to get in the URL params(context.params).

```
params: { slug: book.data().slug }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the page before getStaticProps to see if it's actually receiving the data. I had this same issue, and the error was the previous page wasn't passing the data